# moving divs with jQuery moves whole page in iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, mouseevent

I have some nested divs providing a menu bar and a "draggable" dot as follows...

```
    <div id="content">
        <div id="headermenu" class="headerfixed"></div>
        <div id="articles" class="articlediv"></div>
        <div id="adverts" class="advertfooter"></div>
        <div id="footermenu" class="footerfixed" >
            <div id="footerpreview" class="slideselect">SCALED INNER HTML</div>
            <div id="footerbutton" class="slidebutton"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS for the relevant elements is:

```
    div.slidebutton
    {position:absolute;
    background: url("images/hhgfooterbubble1.png") no-repeat;
    left:45px;
    bottom:8px;
    width:39px;
    height:39px;
    z-index:4;}

    div.footerfixed 
    {position:fixed; background: url("images/hhgfooterbar1.jpg") no-repeat; bottom:0px; left:0px; width:769px;height:49px; visibility: hidden; overflow-x:hidden; z-index:3;}
```

I am using vmousemove to try and move the `footerbutton` but when I touch and drag - the entire page (on an iPad) drags left and right showing black space and the button only moves a little.

```
$('#footermenu').bind('vmousemove', function (event)
    {
        y = event.pageY - window.pageYOffset;
        x = event.pageX;
        l = parseInt(footerbuttondiv.style.left);
        r = l + 39;
        c = 0;

        if (y >= 954)
        {
            if (x>=l && x<=r)
            {
                // alert (y + "," + x + "," + l + "," + r);
                c = x - 19;
                footerpreviewdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
                footerbuttondiv.style.left = c + "px";
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there a way of getting the container `div` `footermenu` to ignore the drag so only `footerbutton` is affected. Any and all assistance gratefully received.

All works fine in Firefox / Firebug no errors.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference to the iPad, but nesting `div`'s inside a `table` inside a `div` is some pretty ugly franken-coding.  Just use all `div`'s to see what happens.

Comment: Removed all tables and focussed the bind onto the footer div. I am still experiencing the same effect - any vmousemove on the footerbutton div drags the whole page in the same direction. I have z-indexes to compensate (content = 0, footermenu = 3, footerbutton = 4) but no joy.

Comment: SOLVED. The answer was the article container for the dynamic html had multiple CSS classes - one of which didn't have overflow-x:hidden; This is the cause of the problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please post your solution below so you can accept your own answer and also help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was within the CSS classes of the "content" and "articles" divs.

In order for the iPad display to remain rigid and not move in response to sideways finger gestures the CSS for these DIV elements must contain the overflow-x:hidden; element.

On checking my own CSS for each element that was displayed while my footer bar was visible I discovered the CSS for the "articles" DIV had a mistake in it.

I altered the DIV to include the overflow-x setting and the side scrolling behaviour has been removed.